# TextInputLayout default error color on Android

Tags: android

Since it is not easy to customize the color of the error in a TextInputLayout, I decided to change my error colour to match the one used by default by TextInputLayout.

In the design guidelines I could not find the definition of the default colour.

Do you know where I can find it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only solution I found was to check the code of TextInputLayout.
I found that the style is

```
<style name="TextAppearance.Design.Error" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/design_textinput_error_color</item>
</style>
```

where

```
<color name="design_textinput_error_color">#FFDD2C00</color>
```

but it seems this is not documented so it can change

Answer (score 1):

Update in 2020.

TextInputLayout error color can be acquired via:

```
ContextCompat.getColor(this, com.google.android.material.R.color.design_error)
```

But it is marked private and can be changed. Approximately color value is:

```
<color name="color_text_input_error_color">#E87850</color>
```